# Environment Change

Tags: powerbi

So, we have three different environment- Development, Testing and Production. We create report on development environment. Now, we create path like, If we publish report on testing or production environment, it automatically change path of different environment and update that report.
How's that possible?

What should I change in source path so that I can test my report.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-query-parameters), which can be changed in the service after deploying your report.  Or a [Deployment Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/cicd/deployment-pipelines/intro-to-deployment-pipelines) with [deployment rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/cicd/deployment-pipelines/create-rules).

> When you deploy content between pipeline stages, you can configure
> deployment rules to change the content while keeping some settings
> intact. For example, if you want a dataset in a production stage to
> point to a production database instead of one in the test stage, you
> can define a rule for this. The rule is defined in the production
> stage, under the appropriate dataset. Once the rule is defined,
> content deployed from test to production, will inherit the value as
> defined in the deployment rule, and will always apply as long as the
> rule is unchanged and valid.